# How do you remove first and last char from a string inside of a list depending on specific sets of characters in the list. (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Now, I understand that the title does not exactly correlate to what I am attempting to figure out, but hopefully, you will understand when you see my code.

First of all, there is a list containing a bunch of information, I will include only the first three.

```
memberList = ['uuid_e04a043abc334bd1a2fbd167bdce1673[MVP+] IgrisGuild Master2020/07/21 '
 '02:35:052020/08/09 00:58:55',
 'uuid_1f12bce8313040a7978d5c51ceb9d82d[VIP] mistercintPrince2020/08/01 '
 '00:31:342020/08/08 23:47:53',
 'uuid_405e46954f804487ae9c18689f0c351b[MVP+] zoucePrince2020/08/06 '
 '20:11:222020/08/08 22:02:04']
```

Next, I remove the first 37 and the last 38 characters because they are all not relevant and they are all present at the exact same length in the list.

```
memberList = [e[37:-38] for e in memberList]
```

I attempted to do something like this, but I can't quite get it down.

```
for i in range(len(memberList):
      if 'Igris' in memberList:
           (remove the first 7 and the last 12 from this specific string inside of the list)
```

What I want it to end up as is as follows.

```
print(memberList)
```

Output:

```
[Igris, mistercint, zouce]
```

Thank you for your consideration, this is my first time using this site and I'm very new to coding, so please pardon my incorrect formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

members = [re.sub( r"([A-Z])", r" \1", member.split()[1]).split()[0] for member in memberList]
print(members)
```

...should give you what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, and sorry if I was not easily understandable in my original message. I put it into my code and it ended up working, but it didn't for specific cases. The cases that didn't end up working had an extra capital such as 'uuid_e04a043abc334bd1a2fbd167bdce1673[MVP+] NytNytroPrince2020/08/01 '
 '00:31:342020/08/08 23:47:53'. If you could either explain your code to me or give me an adjusted solution, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Igris there are several parts to the code. First, we split each member by empty spaces and grab the name: member.split()[1]. Then I use the 're' regex library to put spaces after each capital letter and split again, grabbing the first capital letter word. For your use, if you have something like NytNytroPrince, just find the last instance of a capital letter and cut the string from that point.